# Python scraping splash javascript click

Tags: javascript, python, xpath, splash-screen

I'm trying to use Splash to renderer a webpage with javascript content. I'm using lxml to parse the result.
I need to expand hidden menus. I've found the method to click on element but I don't know how I can click on each result from an xpath search.

Below my xpath filter.

//div[contains(@class,'clickable_area')]

So, I need to perform a "find all" search on this xpath expression and for each of them, click on the object to display hidden informations.

If someone can help me...

Thanks

Comment: Please, if possible, provide the url to the actual target page you are scraping and your current code (as much as possible).

Comment: In this site https://angel.co/markets for example, how can expand all markets(informations technologies, consumers, entreprises...). I need to find each of them and then click on each to expand markets.

Answer (score -1):

Here I will explain you how to get all submenu.

https://angel.co/new_tags/list_children?tag_id=data-tag_id
eg. https://angel.co/new_tags/list_children?tag_id=9217
It will return all submenu of "All Markets"

Then you can collect all "data-tag_id" and pass one by one to URL.

If there is no data-tag_id then it will return error.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I'm most interested by a "general solution" to can perform a multiple search by an xpath pattern and perform an action on each result. But for this website, your solution works perfectly.